# Replacing the character in strings with apostrophes Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, char

I have strings in my data like so: bachelor`’`s

It is a rectangle with an X through it (you can't really see the X here) it is showing up where `curly` apostrophes existed in the data

I am having trouble replacing the character `’` with an apostrophe `'`

If I do a G search on this `’` the closest match I find is

```
Symbol  ⌧   
Name    x in a rectangle box    
Unicode number  U+2327
```

I tried replacing these with a script using

`str.replace(/[\U2327]/g, "'");`
Or
`str.replace(/[\U+2327]/g, "'");`

But nither work

Hmm, I see that the character is acutely being turned into an apostrophe in the post!

[image]

Thanks for any help on this

Goole sheet shawing an expample
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WV1NHa0xX4GcSQD9xKUCJyfHmrcvwd3jqiJD20mqQlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why don't you just use `str = str.replace(/’/g, "'")`?

Comment: I just tried that and it does not work

Comment: Then the quote is only displayed as curly, but it is just a regular straight single quote.

Comment: I added a picture of the issue

Comment: which font do you use? where do they come from? does the web site if any is coded in unicode? I think that t(his is a problem of unicode coding and/or font.

Comment: Your example sheet shows that the [simple replace works fine](https://imgur.com/a/XCbYcPj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code ascii in your sample spreadsheet appears to be 146

Try

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,char(146),"'")
```

[image]

In a script

```
function myFunction() {
  str = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue()
  var pattern = String.fromCharCode(146);
  var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
  Logger.log (str.replace(regex, "'"))
}
```

Comment: Mike, I just tried that but no luck, the problem is I do not think that is the actual character just the one the closest I could find. `Stackoverflow` recognizes the character as it has replaced it with an apostrophe so there must be an actual character code for it

Comment: Can you give the original data in a spreadsheet for instance?

Comment: That usually means that the font being used does not have those particular characters. Try selecting all of the text and changing to Helvetica or some other common font and see if all of the characters show up.

Comment: I add a Goole sheet showing an example of the issue (most of the data is sensitive so can not show a whole lot)

Comment: I tried the suggestion about changing fonts but no luck

Comment: The script changes only one (first) symbol in the text.

Comment: You are right Yuri. I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to try various characters related to the apostrophe characters. For example:

```
str = str.replace(/[⌧’‘`´]/g, "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you able to copy example of the symbol and paste it into code, you don't even need to guess what the character is it. You can just replace it this way:

```
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var text = sheet.getRange('a1').getValue();      // here is your text
  var ch = text[24];                               // here is the symbol
  var reg = RegExp(ch, 'g')
  var new_text = text.replace(reg, "'");
  sheet.getRange('a2').setValue(new_text)
}
```

[image]

In this particular case the symbol is `\u0092`:

```
function main2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var text = sheet.getRange('a1').getValue();
  var new_text = text.replace(/\u0092/g, "'");
  sheet.getRange('a3').setValue(new_text)
}
```

Comment: I tried that, the issue is it is a `nonprinting` character so when I try this there is no character shown and nothing gets converted

Comment: You can click on Run code snippet button and see. It works. It's exactly your text from the spreadsheet and the symbol is picked and replaced successfully.

Comment: Ok, I see you are selecting the 8th character from the string and replacing it. this works but I have these scattered all over the place in strings of different lengths. Do not now have I would use this approach for a general solution to the problem

Comment: If you can pick the symbol once and put it into a variable you can use this variable further to find and change the symbol.

Comment: I've added the solution for this particular symbol. Try it.